# Wrong chapter in heading tufte latex

Tags: sectioning, chapters, tufte

I have a Tufte-book with some chapters and a bibliography and index. This is set up as:

```
\begin (document}

\mainmatter

%then I include several chapters:

\include{Chapter/chaptertitle} 

\end{document}
```

For some reasons, after typesetting, it shows the wrong chapter name in the heading for the last chapters.
Who can help?

Comment: Hi @joran and [welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there.

Comment: Without a full MWE we can't answer this, I'm afraid.